# Reading material for the following strategy to model proportions

Tags: regression, references, proportion

Respone data is a vector of proportions summing to one: $[p_1,...,p_n]$, $\sum p_i = 1$.

We have covariates (discrete + continuous) that we want to model in a linear  mixed model, since we have some random effects.

My plan: take log ratios, $log(p_1/p_n), ..., log(p_{n-1}/p_n)$.

Model this using multivariate mixed model. Backtransform the estimated parameters for calculating fitted vlaues.

**Question:** Is this plan sound? What's some good litterature on this topic?

In particular, I have read a little bit on it, and it seems that there are two main approaches. One seems to align with the above, and another seems to use "distributions on the simplex", and "ilr transformations". I don't quite understand that. Are the methods the same? What's the difference?

The third method is Dirichlet regression, but I find that there's too little litterature on it.